# Why doesn't on('click', function() {}); work properly on IE?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I am creating a small photo viewing script, but I have a problem which is IE. The jquery works proeprly in every other browser, but not in IE.

Here is the following script:

```
$(function() {
$( '.open-img' ).on('click', function() { 
    var src = $( this ).attr( 'src' );
    $( '.inner-pop-up' ).html( '<img src="' + src + '" class="op-img db" />' );
    $( '.cs-outer-pop-up' ).fadeIn(800);
    $( '#cs-main-header-top').fadeOut(500);
    $( '.op-img' ).on('click', function() {
        $( '.cs-outer-pop-up' ).fadeOut(800);
        $( '#cs-main-header-top').fadeIn(800);
    });
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
           $( '.cs-outer-pop-up' ).fadeOut(800);
        }
    });
});
```

});

Here is html: (where the img goes)

```
<div class="cs-outer-pop-up pr db oh" style="display: none">
<div class="inner-pop-up">

</div>
```

here is html: (where the img is to click to)

```
<div class="main-pad ma oh pr db m-t10 m-b10">
                <div class="cs-screenshots w1-ha pr db oh">
                    <ul class="oh"> 
                        <li><div class="outer-b-screen oh b5 db ma"><img src="img/screens/cs1/1.png" alt="Counter-Strike 1.6: Screen 1" class="open-img" /></div></li>
                        <li><div class="outer-b-screen oh b5 db ma"><img src="img/screens/cs1/1.png" alt="Counter-Strike 1.6: Screen 1" class="open-img" /></div></li>
                        <li><div class="outer-b-screen oh b5 db ma"><img src="img/screens/cs1/1.png" alt="Counter-Strike 1.6: Screen 1" class="open-img" /></div></li>
                        <li><div class="outer-b-screen oh b5 db ma"><img src="img/screens/cs1/1.png" alt="Counter-Strike 1.6: Screen 1" class="open-img" /></div></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> 
            </div>
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, so please help me to solve the problem :) 
Thank you :)

Comment: There's no element with a class of `open-img`, what do you *expect* to happen?  This wouldn't "work" in any browser.

Comment: sorry, forgot to add: 

here it is: 
<li><div class="outer-b-screen oh b5 db ma"><img src="img/screens/cs1/1.png" alt="Counter-Strike 1.6: Screen 1" class="open-img" /></div></li>

Comment: Can you update the question to include the actual HTML?  Also, define "doesn't work."  Where does it fail?  When you debug it, what works differently than you expect?

Comment: added html, I am not really sure, because it works in all other browsers but not in IE.. hm...

Comment: solved, it was just a block fro, IE which did not allow me to load scripts on the page :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '.open-img' ).on('click', function() {
```

Code above tries to set on click handler on elements with class "open-img". I can't see it in the HTML code...

(But maybe something other doesn't work)